# Converter and enum to change Foreground color of TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I would like to display in a `TextBlock` my variable `TrainDelay` in a specific format

I used a Converter `IntToTimeSpanConverter` to format TrainDelay  : (mm:ss)

so according to the value of TrainDelay such as:

- Display `Delayed (00:23)` in red color
- Display `On Time (00:00)` in dark color
- Display `In Advance (- 00:15)` in green color

Some code:

```
public class TimeSpanFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int time);
        value = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) || ((TimeSpan)value).Equals(TimeSpan.MinValue))
            return "––:––";
        else if(time > 0)
        {
            return TrainDelay.Delayed + "  " + ((((TimeSpan)value) < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
        else if (time < 0)
        {
            return TrainDelay.InAdvance + "  " + ((((TimeSpan)value) < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            return TrainDelay.OnTime + "  " + ((((TimeSpan)value) < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public enum TrainDelay
{
    OnTime,
    Delayed,
    InAdvance
}
```

I have tried this using `DataTrigger` in this XAML :

```
<TextBlock Name="tb" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="defaultDelay"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=TrainDelay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter}}" Value="Delayed">
                    <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding TrainDelay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

I'm still not having the right result !

I'm Beginner in C# WPF programming , I need help to implement this or maybe have more explanations to really understand the problem

Comment: `TrainDelay` seems to be a property of something. Please show us that class that it is a property of. Or is it? Do any of your bindings work?

Comment: Binding this property `TrainDelay` is working well i used it in other way and i have got the correct result in the TextBlock.
But when i try to change the foreground color it doesn't

Comment: That simplifies everything. See answer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you for  the explanations , the solution seems working correctly . great job ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this Binding does, is it goes and finds the element named `tb`, and looks on that element for a property named `TrainDelay`. Right there it fails, because TextBlock has no property by that name. `TrainDelay` is a property of a viewmodel, not of the control.

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=TrainDelay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatConverter}}" 
    Value="Delayed">
```

If you want to trigger on the "delayedness" of the train, you'll need another converter to convert the `TrainDelay` property into just the enum. Comparing "Delayed" to your formatted time string will never work.

That new converter can look like this. It's just a simplified version of the other one. While I'm at it, I'm going to rewrite your converter to simplify it and remove a lot of redundant code. Redundant code is a bad idea: At first, it's just clutter. Then somebody comes along to maintain the thing a year later, and they waste some time confirming that those three subexpressions are really identical after all. Next year somebody else changes two of them. A year after that, somebody needs to make another change and mistakenly assumes the third one was *supposed* to be different. Meanwhile, somebody else copied and pasted the whole mess, and now you've got more problems.

```
public class TimeToDelayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int time);
        var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) || span.Equals(TimeSpan.MinValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return TimeSpanFormatConverter.SecondsToDelay(time);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TimeSpanFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static TrainDelay SecondsToDelay(int time)
    {
        if (time > 0)
        {
            return TrainDelay.Delayed;
        }
        else if (time < 0)
        {
            return TrainDelay.InAdvance;
        }
        else
        {
            return TrainDelay.OnTime;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int time);

        //  Don't assign this back to value. Assign it to a new variable that's properly 
        //  typed, so you don't need to cast it. 
        var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) || span.Equals(TimeSpan.MinValue))
        {
            return "––:––";
        }
        else
        {
            //  No need to copy and paste the same code three times. 
            var timeStr = ((span < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            return $"{SecondsToDelay(time)}  {timeStr}";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public enum TrainDelay
{
    OnTime,
    Delayed,
    InAdvance
}
```

And then your trigger looks like this. Note that it's using a **different converter** than before.

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding TrainDelay, Converter={StaticResource TimeToDelayConverter}}" 
    Value="Delayed">
```